# pure virtual function and abstract class

Tags: c++, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I have the following classes, Base and Derived and when I compile the compiler complains that it cannot create an instance of DLog because it is abstract.

Can someone tell me how I can fix this error?

I'm guessing it's because not both pure virtual functions are not implemented in the Derived.

```
class Logger
{
public:

    virtual void log(int debugLevel, char* fmt, ...) = 0;
    virtual void log(string logText, int debugLevel, string threadName = "") = 0;

    static Logger* defaultLogger() {return m_defaultLogger;}
    static void setDefaultLogger(Logger& logger) {m_defaultLogger = &logger;}

protected:

    static Logger* m_defaultLogger;
};

class DLog : public Logger
{
public:
    DLog();
    ~DLog();

    static DLog *Instance();
    static void Destroy();

    void SetLogFilename(std::string filename);
    void SetOutputDebug(bool enable);
    std::string getKeyTypeName(long lKeyType);
    std::string getScopeTypeName(long lScopeType);
    std::string getMethodName(long lMethod);

    virtual void log(string logText, int debugLevel)
    {
        Log(const_cast<char*>(logText.c_str()));
    }

    void Log(char* fmt, ...);

private:

    static DLog *m_instance;

    std::string m_filename;
    bool m_bOutputDebug;
};
```

// DLog instantion as a singleton

```
DLog *DLog::Instance()
{
    if (!m_instance)
        m_instance = new DLog();
    return m_instance;
}
```

Comment: You need to implement the PVFs in the derived class, obviously.

Comment: Please please please, don't overload functions with an ellipsis. Will save you hours of hair-pulling and late night debugging.

Comment: @Alex:  Not an overload... its with a capital L the Log function.  the others are lower case...

Comment: But there are two overloads of the `log` method, one with an ellipsis. Use Boost.Format or a similar technique instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
virtual void log(string logText, int debugLevel, string threadName = "") = 0;
```

has not been implemented in class DLog. You have to implement it because it's pure virtual in the base class.

You probably meant this in your first overload of `log` in `DLog`:

```
virtual void log(string logText, int debugLevel, string /*threadname*/)
{
    Log(const_cast<char*>(logText.c_str()));
}
```

EDIT: You also have not implemented the overload of

```
virtual void log(int debugLevel, char* fmt, ...) = 0;
```

Note here though that using the `const_cast` is a very bad idea and is undefined behavior. You can get well defined behavior by doing something like this instead:

```
virtual void log(string logText, int debugLevel, string /*threadname*/)
{
    logText.push_back('\0'); // Add null terminator
    Log(&logText[0]); // Send non-const string to function
    logText.pop_back(); // Remove null terminator
}
```

Better yet though, just make "Log" const-correct in the first place.

Comment: I thought string was null terminated??  Or is it just a char* thats null terminated?

Comment: @Tony: Some `std::string` implementations will have a null terminator there but they are not required to have one, unless you call the `c_str` member. However, you cannot modify the buffer returned by `c_str` and have well defined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

By deriving your `DLog` class from `Logger` you are assuring that you will provide the implementation for all (assuming you don't want `DLog` as an abstract class) pure virtual methods declared in the base class. Here you have not provided implementation to pure virtual functions hence class `DLog` becomes an abstract class. In C++ you can not create an instance of an abstract class hence you get the compiler error. BTW, your base class is missing the virtual destructor.